# knockout js - Display selected nested checkboxes

Tags: arrays, json, list, knockout.js, nested

I have some code that lists some categories and subcategories with checkboxes but i can not get it to show a which checkboxes have been checked in a nested ul. It does return the selected items but not in a ul list.

please could you show me how to display the selected categories and sub catagories in a nested ul. Thanks.

```
var ViewModel = function() {

    var self = this;
    self.selectedCategories = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray();
    self.categories = ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'Hospitality', items: [ 'Bars', 'Caterers', 'Cafes', 'Food To Go', 'Pubs' ] },
        { name: 'Popup', items: [ 'Food Vans', 'Festivals', 'Markets', 'Beer Garden' ] }
    ]);

}
var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);



<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: categories, as: 'category' }">
    <li> <input type="checkbox" name="level-1" data-bind="checked: $root.selectedCategories, attr: {value: name}"><span data-bind="text: category.name"></span></input>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: { data: items, as: 'item' }">
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="level-2" data-bind="checked: $root.selectedItems, attr: {value: item}"><span data-bind="text: item"></span></input></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<div data-bind="text: selectedCategories"></div>
<div data-bind="text: selectedItems"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to store whether a category is selected, and its selected items, in the categories own model. You can make a `computed` in your `ViewModel` to create an array with only selected categories. Here's an example:

```js
var ViewModel = function() {

  var self = this;

  self.categories = ko.observableArray([{
    name: 'Hospitality',
    items: ['Bars', 'Caterers', 'Cafes', 'Food To Go', 'Pubs'],
    selected: ko.observable(false),
    selectedItems: ko.observableArray([])
  }, {
    name: 'Popup',
    items: ['Food Vans', 'Festivals', 'Markets', 'Beer Garden'],
    selected: ko.observable(false),
    selectedItems: ko.observableArray([])
  }]);

  self.selectedCategories = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.categories().filter(function(cat) {
      return cat.selected()
    });
  });
}
var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: categories, as: 'category' }">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="level-1" 
           data-bind="checked: selected, value: name">
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: { data: items, as: 'item' }">
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="level-2" 
               data-bind="checked: category.selectedItems, value: item, enable: category.selected">
        <span data-bind="text: item, style: { 'opacity' : (category.selected() ? 1 : 0.5)}"></span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>


<h2>Selections</h2>
<ul data-bind="foreach: selectedCategories">
  <li>
    <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: selectedItems">
      <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** You had some invalid HTML in your snippet: you can't put a `<span>` element in an `<input>` element.

Comment: Glad I could help.